# Android app custom event history log

Tags: android

For an Android app I want to make a custom history event log which I can display on a screen.   **N.B.  - the events in this are NOT for debugging and have nothing to do with LogCat**.  These are application-domain events related to the ordinary user's use of the program.   This application runs in an industrial environment and may stay running for several days during which time about a thousand log entries might be collected.  Each entry would be a string about 100-150 characters long, so the total size of this log would be well under 1M.

This log should be persistable so if the device is shut off or suffers battery failure or a crash, the log can still be read the next time it's started.  The user can clear the log if he wants.

I'm thinking of creating a class that implements Serializable and "has-a" string array of some kind for the events, then serializing that class out to a file for persistent storage.  The class would have methods for adding new events, clearing events, reading events sorted or filtered by time/date, type, or user (all fields in the event string). When the app is started it would read it in, and every time a new event is logged it would write out a new copy.   For displaying it I would probably use a ListView.

Is this an OK way to do this?    Does Android already have any built-in classes for doing this so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Persistent data entries with sorting and filtering? You are describing an epitome of SQLite usage scenario here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer:
that sounds like something where you should use sqlite for

detail:
I would not go for for serializing a class with a string as you describe for the following reasons:

- you write the same data over and over again ( consumes more resources than needed )
- you would have to be careful when writing to not loose data - especially if you write over your old serialized file in your described scenario of phone-shut down ..
- you would have to implement the needed sorting - you would get all this for free and established with a database

  All you describe sounds really that you should go for a DB here - just to put it on the plate there is also the option to use SharedPreferences - but with your descibed data-size and your need for sorting and stuff I would go for the DB

Comment: I think SQL would be way overkill for this.   This is just one string per log entry.  Filtering can be done with with simple string operators, no need for the complexity of a relational database.   What I really want is a **private** LogCat-_Lite_.   Is LogCat derived from any publicly-visible base classes?

Comment: This answer is in the LQP queue. It should be a comment.

Comment: I added some detail to my answer